# Группировка массива с объектами по заданному селекту JS

Tags: javascript

Имеется массив с объектами, который приходит с бэка:

```
const arr = [{time: "2022-11-25T10:51:26.390Z", и другие поля}, {time: "2022-12-25T10:51:26.390Z"}, {time: "2022-10-25T10:51:26.390Z"}, и так до бесконечности...]
```

На фронте нужно реализовать сортировку по селекту в котором есть поля: "За всё время", "За месяц", "За неделю". Если выбрали такой-то селект, то сгруппируй массив и верни и отобрази на странице эти элементы.

Если кто-то реализовал подобный функционал, поделитесь идеями, как без сильной нагрузки на приложение реализовать этот функционал, а то все мои варианты пока сводятся к огромным вычислениям...

Comment: Это уже не сортировка. Это несколько группировок.

Comment: @ksa Спасибо, видимо, что я сам не особо понял как это должно работать... На текущий момент я вижу тогда это так: создаю функцию, которая принимает 2 аргумента (массив и значение, по которому нужно провести группировку). В теле функции, допустим, прохожу .reduce() по массиву с сравниваю значения и на выходе сгруппированный массив. Подскажите, в правильном ли я направлении думаю?

Comment: Это не должно делаться на фронте. Вы должны на бек отправлять порядок сортировки и диапазон

Comment: @EzioMercer а чем чревата попытка сделать это на фронте? Или имеется ввиду, что сгруппированные данные должны храниться в БД и по мере изменения условий должна "чиститься"? И получается, что при первом запросе к бэку он мне должен отдавать и общий массив и отфильтрованные значения, а я на фронте просто, допустим, через switch(...) case буду регулировать этим?

Comment: 1. Черевата тем что фронт будет виснуть с увеличением количества данных. 2. Нет, бэк не должен отдавать весь массив, он должен отдавать ровно столько сколько нужно (порциями). Далее вы делаете ленивую загрузку данных или же пагинацию, на ваше усмотрение. Бэк все эти манипуляции сделает в разы быстрее чем фронт

Answer (score 0):

Предложу такой вариант...

```js
const arr = [
    {time: "2022-11-25T10:51:26.390Z"}, 
    {time: "2022-12-25T10:51:26.390Z"}, 
    {time: "2023-01-10T10:51:26.390Z"},
    {time: "2022-10-25T10:51:26.390Z"}
]
const mn = month()
const wk = week()
const obj = arr.reduce((r, o) => {
    r['За всё время'].push(o)
    if (month(o.time) === mn) r['За месяц'].push(o)
    if (segment(wk, o.time)) r['За неделю'].push(o)
    return r
}, {'За всё время': [], 'За месяц': [], 'За неделю': []})
console.log(obj)

// Попадает ли дата в отрезок d1 - d2
function segment(wk, date = new Date()) {
    if (typeof date === 'string') date = new Date(date)
    if (date < wk[0]) return false
    if (date > wk[1]) return false
    return true
}

// Определить начало и конец недели
function week(date = new Date()) {
    if (typeof date === 'string') date = new Date(date)
    const n = date.getDay() || 7
    const d = date.getDate()
    let d1 = (new Date(date)).setDate(d + (1 - n))
    let d2 = (new Date(date)).setDate(d + (7 - n))
    d1 = new Date(d1)
    d2 = new Date(d2)
    return [d1, d2]
}

// Определить месяц
function month(date = new Date()) {
    if (typeof date === 'string') date = new Date(date)
    const val = date.toISOString().split('T')[0].match(/\d+\-\d+/)[0]
    return val
}
```